# How to retrieve Steam username using SteamWorks API?

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

How can I obtain the Steam username of the currently used (logged-in) account in my application using the Steam API (which is up and running).

The Steam id can (for example) be obtained by:

```
CSteamID id = SteamUser.GetSteamID();
```

But I cannot find a method to obtain the username.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Account Name

Getting the account name is difficult as there is no API function as far as I know.
But there is a `SteamAppData.vdf` file in the `<SteamInstallPath>/config` folder which looks similar to this:

```
"SteamAppData"
{
    "RememberPassword"  "<0|1>"
    "AutoLoginUser"     "<accountName>"
}
```

You can get the Steam install path with the `SteamAPI_GetSteamInstallPath()` command defined in `steam_api.h`.
Then you can read the file and extract the account name out of it.

## Player Name

Getting the player name is really easy:

In `isteamfriends.h` you'll should find this method:

```
// returns the local players name - guaranteed to not be NULL.
// this is the same name as on the users community profile page
// this is stored in UTF-8 format
// like all the other interface functions that return a char *, it's important that this pointer is not saved
// off; it will eventually be free'd or re-allocated
virtual const char *GetPersonaName() = 0;
```

So `SteamFriends.GetPersonaName()` should give you the player name.

Comment: Is still we need to use this method to get Account Name, or we have now API function?

Answer (score 3):

SteamFriends()->GetPersonaName();